# Remove first item from Array in Javax

Tags: java, arrays

Got an assignment question which asks to return the first item from an array and then remove it. If the array is empty I should return null. Here is my code:

```
public String pop(){
    if(arrayLength == 0){
        return null;
    }else{
        String[] temp = new String[100];
        String firstItem = StringStack[0];
        for(int i = 1; i<StringStack.length; i++){
            temp[i] = StringStack[i];
        }
        StringStack = temp;
        return firstItem;
    }
}
```

The arrayLength variable is set by this method and works fine:

```
public int getLength(){
    int count = 0;
    for (String s : StringStack) {
        if (s != null) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

I cant figure out what it is I am doing wrong here. Another part of this question is I cant use any collections or Systems.arraycopy so I have to use for loops and other basic operators to solve this. It also has to be an array so I cant use array lists or other data structures.

Comment: `The arrayLength variable is set by this method and works fine` I don't see this in code, posted method does not update any instance variable

Comment: I think, what you replace `arrayLength` by `StringStack.length`
https://hastebin.com/wibokixuqa.cs

Comment: `String[] temp = new String[100];` --> `String[] temp = new String[StringStack.length - 1];` then `getLength()` can return `StringStack.length`.

Answer (score 0):

here is version with two fixed problems:

```
public String pop() {
    if(StringStack == null || StringStack.length == 0)
        return null;

    String firstItem = StringStack[0];

    String[] temp = new String[StringStack.length-1]; // allocate proper size
    for(int i = 1; i<StringStack.length; i++){
        temp[i-1] = StringStack[i]; // i-1 for temp array
    }
    StringStack = temp;

    return firstItem;
}
```